# How do I install fonts?

Tags: fonts

How do I install fonts on Ubuntu Linux? I need them to be available in gimp.

Answer (score 455, accepted):

Many fonts are packaged for Ubuntu and available via the "Fonts" category of the Ubuntu Software Center. If you prefer `apt-get`, search for packages starting with *otf-* or *ttf-*.

Font files that are placed in the hidden `.fonts` directory of your home folder will automatically be available (but `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` indicates it will be removed soon.). You can also place them in the `~/.local/share/fonts` directory on newer versions of Ubuntu per the comments below.

You can also double-click on the font file (or select *Open with Font Viewer* in the right-click menu). Then click the **Install Font** button.

If you need the fonts to be available system-wide, you'll need to copy them to `/usr/local/share/fonts` and reboot (or manually rebuild the font cache with `fc-cache -f -v`).

You can confirm they are installed correctly by running `fc-list | grep "<name-of-font>"`

You may need to restart some programs, like OpenOffice Writer, before they actually show the new fonts (usually such programs are caching the font list when they start up).

*Edit: Changed advice to manually install into `/usr/local/share/fonts` instead of `/usr/share/fonts` to reflect comments and best practice.*

Comment: Instead of `~/.fonts`, it's also possible to place fonts in `~/.local/share/fonts`.

Comment: This is no longer true in 16.10. You have to do it through Synaptic or another package installer.

Comment: Manually modifying `/usr/share/fonts` feels wrong to me. I think manually installed system-wide fonts should go to `/usr/local/share/fonts`.

Comment: _fc-cache_ comes with the package _fontconfig_ on latest Ubuntu server versions, so don't forget your `apt-get install fontconfig` if your system cannot find _fc-cache_
And yes, _fc-cache_ also scans /usr/local/share/fonts, so placing them there would be more respectful of Linux filesystem hierarchy.

Comment: Note that if you want to install `mscorefonts` you need to manually download this package https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download since the version in the Ubuntu repositories is broken.

Comment: And where are fonts in Gnome Software? I cannot find them. Ubuntu Software center was discontinued.

Comment: Not all font paths are supported (auto-loaded) equally by applications. In my experience `/usr/share/fonts/` is the most reliable place.

Comment: apt has `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Comment: If the font file is not being picked up by fc-cache, it may be because the file is zipped, even if the file ending is for a font such as `.ttf`. You can verify that the file is a font file and not a zip file with `file your-file.ttf`. If it is showing as a zip file, it can be unzipped with `unzip your-file.ttf`

Answer (score 96):

Copy the fonts to `/usr/local/share/fonts` or a subfolder (such as `/usr/local/share/fonts/TTF`) and then run `sudo fc-cache -fv`. There are some graphical programs you can install to make this easier, but I've never felt the need to try any of them. The Ubuntu wiki page on Fonts [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts) may be of help too.

GIMP will find them in there then.

Comment: you have to paste them as root (in /usr/share/fonts or any subfolder of that path), so in order to do so I use gksu nautilus and access the path as root.

Comment: You can use type `sudo mv <original file path> /usr/local/share/fonts` into the terminal to copy/paste it.

Comment: `There are some graphical programs you can install to make this easier`: Well, let's hear them.

Answer (score 60):

Installation of fonts from 3rd party websites is almost too easy. Download and save the file somewhere to your computer:

[image: Font File]

Then double click the font to load the font interface:

[image: Font Selection]

Select the Install Font button located at the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: Is works and is easy to use, but it can be slow with large font folders, and if you have to install multiple fonts opening 50 windows is annoying when you can just copy the fonts to the fonts directory and update the font cache - but this does works fine when installing a few new fonts. [Sort of relevant on speed and terminal v gui](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/12246/178596).

Comment: It is `gnome-font-viewer`. right?

Comment: @Pandya Yes, it is

Comment: So what Happens behind the scene, when you click "Install Font"? OK. I figured out. It is installed under `~/.fonts/`

Answer (score 18):

You don't have to install as root. Create a folder called `.fonts` in your home directory (if you don't already have one), drop the font file in there, run Gimp, job done.

(You may have to enable Edit->Preferences->Views->Show hidden and backup files in Nautilus to be able to see `.fonts` and other ‘hidden’ folders in your home, if you haven't already.)

Comment: You do not need to run Gimp to activate fonts. Copying font files to `~/.fonts` and running `fc-cache -fv` is enough.

Comment: Gimp was mentioned here because the question specifically mentioned wanting to use the new font in gimp

Comment: If you want see the hidden folders in home directory, just hit `Ctrl + H` and press it again hide the folders.

Answer (score 14):

[**Font Manager**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/font-manager/)

Application for *Install* and *Manage* fonts.

Can install Multiple Fonts.

To install fonts Click on ***Manage Fonts*** Button and select ***Install Fonts*** Option.

[image]

Font Manager can be installed from [apps.ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/font-manager/) or and with **Software Centre**. If with commandline ;

```
sudo apt-get install font-manager
```

Comment: This tool is interesting but slow and very basic. You still need to obtain font files manually in order to install fonts.

Answer (score 12):

If you install font(s) in folder `.fonts` in your home directory (another directory `$HOME/.local/share/fonts` in ubuntu 18.04 is ok) , you may need to run `fc-cache -rv` (**not** `sudo`) in order to cache fonts in your home directory as well.

[image: fc-cache -rv]

Answer (score 7):

## Installing font is just copying its file to specific directory.

There can be different directories on different systems. For example at my system they are:

- `/usr/share/fonts/` — fonts for all users
- `~/.local/share/fonts/` — fonts for particular user

There can be any subdirectories you want. It may help you to organize your font collection.

Here is the command to get list of font files that your system uses.

```
fc-list -f '%{file}\n' | sort
```

Look at it and you'll get the idea of where fonts are located in your system.

Answer (score 5):

There is also an application called `fontmatrix` that can help install and manage fonts on Ubuntu. To quote the [introduction](http://fontmatrix.net/node/10) on the [website](http://fontmatrix.net/):

> Fontmatrix is a real Linux font manager, available on any platform and as well for KDE (which already had Kfontinstaller) as for Gnome.
>   It's purpose is to recursively query the fonts (ttf, ps & otf) in the directories you give it to search, sort them quickly, (avoiding bugged or broken ones) and show them.
>   Then, you can tag them, sub-tag, re-sort according various tags, preview... Even create a pdf Font Book...

[image: Fontmatrix screenshot]

Fontmatrix has been available to [install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/fontmatrix) from the Ubuntu universe repository since jaunty, and version 0.6.0+svn20100107-2ubuntu2 is currently in maverick and natty. A brief [explanation](http://fontmatrix.net/node/10) about using fontmatrix is available on their website.

Comment: FontMatrix isn't exactly a "script"...  ;-)

Comment: I guess it is a bit more complex than what most post people would consider a script. I have gone ahead and edited the answer to refer to it as an application instead.

Comment: Answer has become outdated, this tool is no longer available in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

Also, there are lots of fonts available as software packages. Font packages are named in the form ttf-* or otf-*. It is better to install fonts as packages instead of manually if possible. You can use tools such as Synaptic, apt-get or the Ubuntu Software Centre. The Software Centre has a dedicated fonts section.

Comment: And where are fonts in Gnome Software? I cannot find them. Ubuntu Software center was discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to manually installing them inside `~.fonts` (see bobince's answer) and FontMatrix (what nhandler shows you), there is also another font manager aptly named [Font Manager](http://code.google.com/p/font-manager/) ([install Ubuntu package](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/font-manager) for 10.10, or [download package](http://code.google.com/p/font-manager/downloads/list) for 10.04 and maybe older versions) that is quite lightweight (and has a Gtk GUI).

Comment: Does this tool allows automatic installing or I should search for font packages manually?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have fonts available *exclusively* to Gimp, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/320794/58950).

In a nutshell, you copy the fonts files to Gimp's own font folder, or tell Gimp where you have the folder(s) with your fonts.

Answer (score 2):

[Another question, about installing Google Fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984563/how-to-download-and-install-the-roboto-mono-font), was closed as a duplicate of this one, though it isn't really (being rather narrow).

A better answer than the one provided there (i.e. to go to Google Fonts and look up the font and go through their weird downloading system) is to get it directly from Github, e.g.:
[Roboto Mono font files](https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/apache/robotomono)

The rest of them are available at https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/apache, and there's also a ZIP file of them available from the main https://github.com/google/fonts#readme page.

So, if you want to script this stuff (e.g. regularly download the latest version), you can do it with a Git checkout, or by using wget or curl to pull down the exact files you want.

PS: There's another duplicate question at "[Downloading Google Fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696736/downloading-google-fonts)". It details some other methods, like using an installer script from googlecode.com and (for more than the Google Fonts) using tasksel.

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

1. Download the file containing the desired fonts.
2. Go the directory where the downloaded file is.
3. Right click on the file. A black "Box" will appear with many commands.
4. Select "OPEN WITH FONTS." Right click on it.
5. Another box'll appear. You'll see a green "INSTALL" button at the top right corner.
6. Click on that and the fonts will get installed.

You can go into the fonts directory or use a program like LibreOffice to verify the installed fonts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ever using Windows WSL2, you can link your Windows fonts to Ubuntu's ones.

```bash
ln -s /mnt/c/Windows/Fonts ~/.local/share/fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use [gfinstall](https://github.com/realpvn/gfinstall) script, install it and you just say `gfinstall whicheverFont` and it will install it, you can also specify it to install locally (for the current user) or globally for all users

Edit: I made this script so that I don't have to download, copy and paste fonts each time