# How do you download a font and then install it?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

to use for various stuff... thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install fonts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most modern font types are really easy to install. If you're using 10.04 or newer, you should be able to open the font viewer by double clicking on the font, and simply clicking the "install" button.

However, if you want to do it manually (sometimes it helps with organization), it's not much more difficult. All you have to do is move the font to your font directory and then update your cache.

If you look at the contents of `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`, you can see all of the places where your fonts are stored. Personally, I like to put my fonts in `/usr/share/fonts/`, but that requires an account with sudo privileges (since the fonts are owned by 'root'). If you only need the font for a single user account, you can simply drag-and-drop the font into the `~/.fonts/` folder. If you can't find a `~/.fonts/` folder, no problem! Just use `mkdir ~/.fonts` to create it.

Once you've put your font(s) in the correct folder, open up a terminal and type:

`sudo fc-cache -f -v`

This updates your font cache, and now your new fonts should be usable!

Answer (score 0):

Is it that difficult?

What I do is to download the font file (ttf or whatever), to open it by double clicking on it then I click in the "Install" button which appears on the botton of the "gnome-font-viewer application.

The font is immediately installed and ready to be used. Sorry if I misunderstood something in the question but it reads: "How do you download a font and then install it?"

A screenshot is placed here to illustrate:
[image]

*BTW: There are several "font viewer/manager" which includes but not limits to: FontForge and KFontView (for KDE, also running in gnome)*

Depending on the source, the font file may be inside of a compressed file. Just extract it and you will get the ttf.