# Install MS Truetype Fonts system-wide for all users

Tags: apt, fonts, fontconfig

I would like to install the MS Truetype Fonts that come through the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Accepting the license, the process completes without any errors. The fonts end up in

> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts

as expected. Just to be sure, I also did a

```
sudo fc-cache -f -s -v
```

which among other things says in its output:

> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts: caching, new cache contents: 60 fonts, 0 dirs

So far, so good (and inline with question [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)) However, when I then open any font dialog (e.g. in OpenOffice or the font dialog of the terminal) I don't see all of the new fonts. For Arial, the standard form is missing, but bold and italic are there. Times New Roman is missing altogether.

I can use nautilus to browse to the font directory, double click the `Arial.ttf` file and see the font in all its beauty. I can even click the install button then and the font is copied over to my personal `./fonts` directory and from there on visible to my apps. But it is not picked up from the system directory.

How do I get these fonts available system-wide for all users?

Comment: Do the fonts show up if you run `fc-list` as a user?  If not, does clearing the contents of `~/.fontconfig/` help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Argh, by coincidence I just found the solution. There was a file called `~/.fonts.conf` in my home directory that seems to come from Fontmatrix and had a list of rejected fonts, among them the ones I found missing. Simply deleting this file solved the problem. I
remember that I had played around with Fontmatrix but I'm not sure what caused it to create this file. Anyway, problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

I found out, after having similar problems, that in my folder (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts) there was a file, saying that my licens failed - it gave me a command to use in the terminal to get prompted another licens agreement, which this time made it work.

Netflix Desktop worked like a charm after that! (well... truth be told, installations was needed, but it was all automatically done after that!)

Comment: Could you enter in more details? If I had the same issue, what steps should I follow to fix the problem? Edit your answer and add that information.