# Is there a graphical way of installing fonts in 11.10/Gnome 3

Tags: fonts, gnome, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

When testing 11.10, I wanted to install some fonts. However, it seems that I cannot simply double click a font file to install it. I've tried searching google, but I haven't found anything that says the gnome3 can't do this.  Is this going to be addressed? Is there a way I can install new fonts easily? (I know of the manual copying of the fonts to /usr/share/fonts/, but I'm just curious if there is something easier I've been missing.)

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Double click on the font, and on the right hand side of the font viewer click on "Install Font".

[image: Install font]

Alternatively, the manual way is to crate a folder called .fonts in your home directory and save fonts in there.

Also there is this wiki page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts

Comment: That method worked for me in Natty, but in Oneiric, when I double click a font, it says that there is no application suitable to open this file. My question was asking if such a method exists in gnome-3, or is planned to exist.

Comment: It does exist in GNOME3. In a thread on http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/gnome-3-to-get-a-new-font/ for example Stephen Judge asks how to install a font in GNOME 3. The follow up suggests opening and clicking install. It is possible then that you have found a bug in oneiric rather than GNOME3.

Comment: I use oneiric and it works. After double clicking on a font, it appears a window preview and the button "Install font".

Comment: Try to right click your downloaded font, select the voice "property" and next select the tab "Open with".
In my case I have one program available and selected, that is **gnome-font-viewer**, as reported also by @Luis. Install it trough _Ubuntu Software Center_.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a .fonts folder in your home directory. Then drag the fonts in to the folder. This allows for a mass install of fonts.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran in to this problem, all you have to do is install `gnome-font-viewer` I think it is not installed by default.

Answer (score -1):

To install fonts on Ubuntu 11.10, try this:

1. Download the font.
2. Execute: `sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom`
3. Execute: `sudo mv <caminho.onde.esta.o.arquivo>/Monaco_Linux.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom`
4. Execute: `sudo fc-cache -f -v`