# How do I install the Frutiger font?

Tags: 11.04, installation, fonts

Couldn't find it in Synaptic nor in help.ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frutiger isn't a free font and so (as far as I know) isn't included in any Ubuntu packages, nor can you use `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` (which johanvdw alluded to) to install it.

If you can get your hands on a copy of the font, installing it is really easy. If only you want to use it, just copy the files (they'll usually be .ttf or .otf files) into the `.fonts` folder in your home directory. If the folder doesn't exist yet, just go ahead and create it. Or just follow these directions:

- [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

If you have multiple accounts on your computer and want everybody to be able to use the font, you'll need to copy the files to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`. You'll probably need root privileges to do this (try running `sudo nautilus`).

Alternatively, you might want to try Bitstream Vera; it's a high-quality free font, very similar to Frutiger. Just install the `ttf-bitstream-vera` package.

Comment: You are correct, I thought it was part of msttcorefonts, which is not the case.

Comment: No problem! I was going to leave you a comment to say so, but I didn't have the ability to do so until now :P

Comment: OK found a copy and installed it, no problem

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it. :)