# How can I install ecofont?

Tags: fonts

ex.: on Ubuntu 11.04 - how can I install ecofont?

http://www.ecofont.com/

Comment: It seems to be Windows versions of it only, so you'd have to run it through Wine.

Comment: @Lance - do you mean the ecofont TTF itself or the entire software package?

Comment: only the font, no bloatware pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant install ecofonts to replace your fonts automatically because the software is made for Windows only but you can use the TTF installed in the windows version to be used on your documents:

1. Make a new directory /usr/share/fonts. Can be /usr/share/fonts/miscttf.
2. copy the ttf from the install package to that folder.
3. Update the available ttf fonts on your system using `ttmkfdir mkfontdir fc-cache /usr/share/fonts/miscttf`

Or you can just double click on the ttf file and click install:

- [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts/3772#3772)

After that you will be able to use the ecofonts on your documents and print them instead of the normals ones available.