# Is there a way to install multiple fonts on Ubuntu without needing to do them one at a time?

Tags: 11.04, installation, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

This has been itching at me for a while and It would be great to know if theres a way to do this because, I have lots of fonts (ttf) I want to install but dont wanna do it 1 at a time.

Comment: One of the answers in the question above covers this very well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for your user? Create a hidden directory in your home folder named .fonts. Drop all your fonts in the directory.

```
cd
mkdir .fonts
```

Copy the fonts to that directory. Voila!