# How can I install Lucida Grande font using apt-get?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

I am looking for a package and repository from where I can install `Lucida Grande` font and eventually others.

Answer (score 0):

That's an Apple font used on Mac's.  I doubt it is available in a legitimate repository.  If you have a Mac, you can copy it.

Comment: I wasn't asking about a specific type of repository? ;) And, btw Java includes this font.

Comment: ... have you checked the licensing restrictions for doing this?