# Which software is used in Ubuntu for supporting Gill sans font Just like MS Office in Windows

Tags: fonts

Which software is used in Ubuntu for supporting "Gill sans" font Just like "MS Office" in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Once the font was installed in Ubuntu any software will be able to use it. See the following question on how to install a font:

- [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

[Gillius](http://screenshots.debian.net/package/ttf-adf-gillius), a *"purified variation"* of the Gill sans font from Arkandis Digital Foundry can even be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: yaa thankyou.as you given link it's provide by the 3rd party.  "installation of fonts from 3rd party websites is almost too easy. Download and save the file somewhere to your computer"            Is there any other product of ubuntu.?Because I don't want to use 3rd party tools.

Comment: It's not the software, it's the **font data** you will install. They are not always Open Source (in the case of Gill because the **name** - not the font - is copyright protected) therefore they may not be available from Ubuntu but from other sources. Gill fonts are availably to **buy** e.g. [from fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/gill-sans#product_top).