# Missing adobe helvetica bold fonts

Tags: fonts

When I run my application I have this errors

```
////////////////////
% WIDGET_DROPLIST: Requested font does not exist:
                    -adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--12-120-75-75-p-70-iso8859-1.
///////////////////////
```

Can someone point me to which file I should install to get this fonts. I rather not edit my code to look for other fonts.

Answer (score 3):

The Helvetica from Adobe fonts are not ttf so it's likely that it will be very ugly. You may replace them with something similar to Helvetica like `fonts-freefont-ttf` package, or use sans-serif, as described in the [Debian FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/Fonts/FAQ):

```
nano -w ~/.fonts.conf
```

This will create the fonts file, now just put the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">

<fontconfig>

<!-- Helvetica is a non true type font, and will look bad. This
replaces it with whatever is the default sans-serif font -->

<match target="pattern" name="family" >
<test name="family" qual="any" >
<string>Helvetica</string>
</test>
<edit mode="assign" name="family" >
<string>sans-serif</string>
</edit>
</match>
<dir>~/.fonts</dir>

</fontconfig>
```

This will replace any finding to the helvetica font for sans-serif.

Comment: How can you use Adobe fonts??

Comment: @Lucio you don't, you install equivalents like Freefonts, or just replace them for something else

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running some Adobe app. The steps to get the font in the Ubuntu system are:

1. Find the specific Font you need (It must be a TTF file).
2. Create (if not already present) the folder ~/.fonts and inside of it place the Font file.
3. Load the app you are using. It should find the font now.

In my case and to solve some LibreOffice issues between documents, I normally grab all TTF files inside the C:\Windows\Fonts folder and paste them in the ~/.fonts folder.

Other have also suggested to change the folder ~/.fonts to `/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype` but for me the fonts in my home folder works.

You may also like to read [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

Comment: just FYI, Helvetica isn't TTF.

Comment: @Braiam Are you sure because searching for "Helvetica TTF" gives me too many results where I can download the .ttf file. I don't know much about which are or which are not, but the answer is pointing to how to add more fonts (easily) to Ubuntu. BTW a comment would have been enough.

Comment: The problem is that "Helvetica" is a big family of fonts, so obviously you will get thousand of hits, but "adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal", will take you to this [unsolved thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/1997/12/msg00425.html) and others. [This](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/reference/OldXfonts/fonts.alias) will show an aliases for that specific font which is Helvetica Bold that isn't also TTF. Your answer was wrong, since you didn't took into account the font name/family and the specific nuances of the question.

Comment: Holy mother. That is some big family (Italian mafia maybe?). Thanks for the clear up.