# Japanese and european languages font list

Tags: fonts, japanese

Where can I find a complete list of the fonts available for Ubuntu? I need in particular those for all European languages and Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think such a list even exist! Fonts are invented or modifyed every second.
But don't let that stop you, just download the fonts you like and install, for that end use font-manager.
AFAIK. Ubuntu supports all kinds of fonts, I even have Futhark installed (Old Norce Runes).

Answer (score 0):

There are fonts without end. A good place to look is [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts) or [Free Japanese Fonts](http://www.freejapanesefont.com/).

How to install fonts on Ubuntu, you can read [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/3697/367165).

To simply load and install Google Fonts, you can use `typecatcher`.

```
sudo apt-get install typecatcher
```

[image]

Comment: @ilariari Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)