# How To Install Multiple Fonts At Once From .zip Files?

Tags: fonts

Well I did search through AskUbuntu and found some threads where people are asking about how can they install multiple fonts at once? I know the process. I have to copy-paste all the fonts, .ttf/.otf files inside of .font hidden folder and then rebuild the font cash via this command...

```
fc-cache -rv
```

This is crystal clear. I just want to know this...

I downloaded 10+ .zip font files. When I extracted the .zip folders I see within each folder there are couple of files. A readme file, a .ttf/.otf file and in some cases some variants of the fonts. Like bold.ttf, ultra_bold.ttf, semi_bold.ttf, black.ttf etc. I am not sure what these additional files are but I guess these are mainly variants of the core fonts. However my question is...

Do I need to extract all the .zip files manually and then copy only .ttf/.otf files and then paste them manually in .font folder? Or I can use a terminal command which will do everything on behalf of me. Here by the word `everything` I meant...

1. Extracting the .zip files
2. Copying only .ttf/.otf files
3. Pasting only the .ttf/.otf files into .font folder
4. Finally installing the .ttf/.otf files in Ubuntu

Sorry for asking a broad question. But to avoid down votes I had to make sure I am not asking anything which is asked before. And thanks in advanced for all your helps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a one-liner in a terminal. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the commands below. Replace `<your_font_zips>` with the folder name, where you have placed your zip font files.

```
cd <your_font_zips>
# next command extracts all TTF and OTF files into your `.fonts` folder.
unzip "*.zip" "*.ttf" "*.otf" -d ${HOME}/.fonts
# next command rebuilds font cache
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

If you want to remove the fonts again, then simply delete the TTF files in your `.fonts` folder and rebuild the font cache.

More about fonts and Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/3697/367165).

---

And yes, you need all TTF files.

**TTF and/or OTF**

I quote:

> OTF is more likely to be a “better” font, as it supports more advanced
>   typesetting features (smallcaps, alternates, ligatures and so on
>   actually inside the font rather than in fiddly separate expert set
>   fonts). It can also contain either spline (TTF-style) or Bezier
>   (PostScript Type 1-style) curves, so hopefully you're getting the
>   shapes the font was originally designed in and not a
>   potentially-poorer-quality conversion.

<sub>[Source](https://superuser.com/a/96399/427428)</sub>

Comment: You put a different command few minutes ago! You mean I should run this one "unzip "*.zip" "*.ttf" "*.otf" -d ${HOME}/.fonts; sudo fc-cache -f -v" instead of the one you gave few minutes ago?

Comment: Yes, this is the final tested version =)

Comment: We don't need the `find`

Comment: don't forget to change the directory

Comment: sorry for the typo...

Well I have 3 parallel questions... 

1- Lets say I want to delete some fonts from system. How can I do so?
2- I don't know much about scripting. From your words what I understand is I can open a file in the font folder and then copy paste the commands you supplied. And then I should run the file with font archives. Following this I opened a gedit file in the font folder where .zip files are then copycat your commands within the file. But now how can I run the file using font archive? I don't see any application named font archive rather an app named archive manager

Comment: 3- Last question is if I install fonts within .fonts folder will all the user get permission to access the fonts? Or I have to install them insdie /use/share/fonts? Unfortunately I can't see any /use/share/fonts folder anywhere...

4- One last question. When should I run sudo fc-cache -f -v this command?

Comment: I have revised the answer. I confusing things away.

Comment: hm I see you removed the script commands. Sorry for asking childish questions. In fact I have started ubuntu and even linux just 15 days ago. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23498/discussion-between-a-b-and-mike-friedman).

Comment: `sudo fc-cache -f -v` seems to load fonts from `/root/.fonts` not from `${HOME}/.fonts`

Answer (score 4):

*Addendum to the accepted answer:*

Run `fc-cache -f -v` **without** `sudo`.

If you use `sudo`, as indicated by the accepted answer, `fc-cache` will only process the root's fonts folder, while ignoring the user's fonts folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not a one liner but here is slightly more robust script that works on Linux as well as OSX. Here we download codefonts and install it without overwriting existing files.

```
#!/bin/bash
#fail if any errors
set -e
set -o xtrace

temp_dir=~/Downloads/codefonts
wget -P ${temp_dir} https://github.com/chrissimpkins/codeface/releases/download/font-collection/codeface-fonts.zip

if test "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ; then
  # MacOS
  fonts_dir="$HOME/Library/Fonts"
else
  # Linux
  fonts_dir="$HOME/.local/share/fonts"
  mkdir -p $fonts_dir
fi

# -n option avoids overwriting
set +e
unzip -n ${temp_dir}/codeface-fonts.zip "fonts/*.ttf" "fonts/*.otf" "*fonts/.pcf.gz" -d ${temp_dir}
set -e
cp -rnv ${temp_dir}/fonts ${fonts_dir}

if test "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ; then
  # Copy SF Mono for MacOS
  cp /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Fonts/*.otf "$fonts_dir/"
fi

# Reset font cache on Linux
if which fc-cache >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "Resetting font cache, this may take a moment..."
    fc-cache -f "$fonts_dir"
fi

echo "codefonts installed to $fonts_dir"
```