# set fallback font for default serif and sans-serif

Tags: fonts

Default sans-serif font which is used in system, doesn't have some characters from Middle-Eastern languages. So I want to set a fallback font to be used when some symbols are missing.

AFAIK, it's related to `fontconfig` and `fonts.conf` files. Here is my current `fonts.conf` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>sans</family>
        <prefer>
                <family>FONTNAME</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

where `FONTNAME` is the font which have all symbols. It works, but after setting this, the default font disappeared and whole system use `FONTNAME` as default sans font. (Note that, `FONTNAME` has latin characters too.)

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier to install the Ubuntu package for your needed characters if available: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/fonts/

Otherwise, to answer your question, the first font with a matching character/glyph in the preferred list is the font used. If you don't want `FONTNAME` used as the default everywhere, then you need to add it to the list after the primary. This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
                <family>ORIGINAL_SANS_FONT</family>
                <family>YOUR_FONT</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

I suggest using: `sans-serif` instead of `sans`, because it is the actual name in the fontconfig. `sans` is an alias.

Comment: This works on my KDE neon 5.13.5 (based on Ubuntu 16.04) to solve an issue with Inkscape failed to choose previously correct `sans-serif` font family. This issue happened after full upgrading from 5.12.0 and is now solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/3772/986830) you can simply find and download a TTF file ([example](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Symbols)) that contains the glyphs that you need. Double-click to open the font file in the font viewer, and then click the install button.

You don't need to manually set any config up - the system will automatically fall back to your font if the default font is missing glyphs that your new font contains.