# Downloading Google Fonts

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

Is it possible to download all google fonts and have them available under Ubuntu? This would help my webdev.

Comment: I stopped at downloading and checking the script. If the command itself errors out or does not work leave a comment since this is from a 2011 source.

Answer (score 1):

An easier method is to get them directly from Github: https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/apache. Each font has its own subdirectory, with uncompressed font files.

There's also a ZIP file of them available from the main https://github.com/google/fonts#readme page.

So, if you want to script this stuff (e.g. regularly download the latest version), you can do it with a Git checkout, or by using wget or curl to pull down the exact files you want.

PS: This thread is a dup of "[How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)".

Answer (score 0):

If you trust [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/automatically-install-all-google-web.html):

```
cd ~/Downloads && wget http://webupd8.googlecode.com/files/install-google-fonts
chmod +x install-google-fonts
./install-google-fonts
```

In case anyone need to check without downloading: [this is the source code](http://webupd8.googlecode.com/files/install-google-fonts) for "install-google-fonts":

```
$ more install-google-fonts 
# Original author: Michalis Georgiou <mechmg93@gmail.comr>
# Modified by Andrew http://www.webupd8.org <andrew@webupd8.org>

sudo apt-get install mercurial

_hgroot="https://googlefontdirectory.googlecode.com/hg/"
_hgrepo="googlefontdirectory"

echo "Connecting to Mercurial server...."
if [ -d $_hgrepo ] ; then
    cd $_hgrepo
    hg pull -u || return 1
    echo "The local files have been updated."
    cd ..
else
    hg clone $_hgroot $_hgrepo || return 1
fi
echo "Mercurial checkout done or server timeout"
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/google-fonts/
find $PWD/$_hgrepo/ -name "*.ttf" -exec sudo install -m644 {} /usr/share/fonts/t
ruetype/google-fonts/ \; || return 1
fc-cache -f > /dev/null
echo "done."
```

Comment: I better do not make my pc dependent on any dubious source. Can I use google fonts for a commercial purpose?

Comment: yes: https://developers.google.com/fonts/ "The fonts in the directory are all released under open source licenses; you can use them on any non-commercial or commercial project." 1st part: you can always remove mercurial when done if that is an issue. All the other parts in the script seem fine to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have much easier way with these terminal commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

And it will show you a bunch of packages collection, and then simply select :

> [*] Large selection of font packages

And then give it an OK.
Hope it satisfy your design needs :)

Comment: That... does not include google-fonts or if it does pulls in a lot more I'd believe. Plus your command can be reduced to 1: `sudo apt-get install {package}^` . The ^  in there makes it a tasksel task.  Works for all tasks.

Comment: Don't know how to select anything. It also had preselections I didn't know how to delete.