# Fonts in Netbeans

Tags: fonts

I installed Netbeans and I noticed that the fonts that I had in my GUI on Windows is not the same and I cant find the font anywhere in the list of fonts. How can I get all the fonts into Netbeans

Comment: Possibly related to [How do I install fonts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts/3706)

Netbeans almost certainly uses the fonts installed on your operating system (not its own Netbeans fonts), and Ubuntu comes with different fonts than Windows. So to get specific fonts in Ubuntu, you'll have to install them yourself.

Comment: do tried **options -> fonts & colors -> profile** ??