# Languages in Notepad++ in Ubuntu

Tags: language-support

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed Notepad++ using wine it successfully installed. Now I want to type Telugu text using Telugu (KaGaPa phonetic). I changed Encoding in UTF-8 but it's not showing Telugu text - it's showing boxes. What to do to display Telugu text?

Comment: How were you typing in KaGaPa phonetic. Is it in Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: It is in Ubuntu

Comment: How can I add Telegu phonetic in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you ever written Telegu text in Notepad++ in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to view Telugu on NPP in WINE.

You first need to configure the font used to display the text. You can change the font by

1. Going to Menu -> **Settings** -> **Style Configurator**
2. Change the font there.

I change the font for **Global Style** and enforced this global style for all source types by using **Enable Global Font** option. Use an unicode font with Telugu support. You can use *Noto Sans Telugu*, but in my system that made the English text unreadable. So, I used **Giduga** font, which can display both English and Telugu scripts. You can download the fonts from this site http://fonts.siliconandhra.org/ (It's the first link)

Check this question for help installing font - [How do I install fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)

Once you changed the font, you can write Telugu in Notepad++.

Here is a screen-shot of Telugu in NPP. (Forgive me if that magically appears to be a bad word. I typed that one totally random)

[image: telugu in npp]

Comment: How to add Gidugu in Languages..

Comment: @RindhuKondaparthy Check this link for help installing font http://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts

Answer (score 0):

1. Open System Settings.
2. Click the third option called **Language Support**.
3. It will open a new window. Go to the *Install/Remove Languages...* option.
4. Select the language which you want to install and click the *Apply* button.
5. Go to System Settings again and select **Text Entry**.
6. In the Text Entry window you can find **+/-** symbol to add. Select Telugu font and click *Add*.
7. Restart the system to start using the new font.

Comment: I selected Telugu language but it is not working in Notepad++. Other than Notepad++ all languages are working in Ubuntu. In Notepad ++ only English language working and if we press Enter button it is showing as CR LF

Comment: press shift + windows(super) +space-bar key to change language mode.

Comment: click on right most top , you find En symbol to change language mode . select Telugu .

Answer (score 0):

Install Telugu font easily by issuing this command in terminal.
Use anyone of the below commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-te language-pack-te-base
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get install ttf-telugu-fonts
```

or

```
$ sudo apt-get install ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-indic-fonts language-pack-te
```

Comment: You can edit your answer to add this to the existing answer. Because this is not solely.

Comment: The package `ttf-telugu-fonts` is not present in the Ubuntu archive for 16.04+. The new package name is `fonts-telu`.