# How can you install new fonts to LibreOffice snap?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, snap

can anybody tell me how to install new fonts in LibreOffice snap? Is there any font manager for this?

Answer (score 10):

You must copy your fonts into `~/.local/share/fonts/` folder, then in terminal type

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

Go to the `~/snap/libreoffice/current/` path and make a link to `~/.local/share/fonts/` folder by the command below:

```
ln -s {source-filename} {symbolic-filename}
```

i.e. here in particular

```
ln -s ~/.local/share/fonts/ .local/share/fonts
```

**Note:** According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/3706/298314), the `.fonts` folder will be removed at some point hence the recommendation to use `.local/share/fonts` instead.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04: I've tried it and it works for snaps libreoffice and firefox. Using `.fonts` works for libreoffice snap but not for firefox snap.

Answer (score 1):

Close LibreOffice, if it is open.

Open Terminal - hold "Ctrl", "Alt" and press "T" - then enter:

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

Change your "working" directory - that is, where you *are* in Terminal - to that of LibreOffice:

```
cd ~/snap/libreoffice/current
```

Create a symbolic link ("shortcut") to your font folder:

```
ln -s /home/your-ubuntu-username/.local/share/fonts
```

Then run this command:

```
ln -s ~/.fonts .fonts
```

This *should* work (it did for me just then!) and I've tried to make it as easy to follow as possible - but you don't feel comfortable using Terminal commands, you can always switch to the "regular" version of LibreOffice...

Open Ubuntu Software and search for "libreoffice" - remove the one that has references to "snap" or "snapcraft.io" when you click on it (i.e. on the page that has the picture, description, etc...) - it *should* have these references under the "Details" section towards the bottom.

Hit the "back" arrow and install the "regular" version of the LibreOffice programs you need to use - these should *not* contain *any* references to "snap" or "snapcraft.io" under the "Details" section at the bottom.