# Why are most of my fonts missing from LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04LTS with LibreOffice version 6.1.0.3.

I have a ton of fonts installed:

```
$ fc-list | wc -l
379
$ fc-list | head
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Medium.ttf: Lato,Lato Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg/TlwgTypo-Bold.ttf: Tlwg Typo:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-SemiboldItalic.ttf: Lato,Lato Semibold:style=Semibold Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Serif:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-kalapi/Kalapi.ttf: Kalapi:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/fonts-gujr-extra/Rekha.ttf: Rekha:style=Medium
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg/TlwgTypewriter-BoldOblique.ttf: Tlwg Typewriter:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/UbuntuMono-RI.ttf: Ubuntu Mono:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam/AnjaliOldLipi.ttf: AnjaliOldLipi:style=Regular
```

but inside the LibreOffice Writer I can only see a dozen of Ubuntu fonts (see screenshot).

What's going on?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you by any chance install the snap version (check by running `snap list`)? Then I wouldn't be very surprised given the restrictions of snap packages.

Comment: Yeah, it's a snap package. I think I installed it via the UI, not knowing that it'd be different to what I'd get via apt install. I removed the snap package, installed the proper package via apt install, and now the fonts work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To keep getting the benefits of snap packages there is a bit of a hacky solution available over here that might solve your issue.

[How can you install new fonts to LibreOffice snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885728/how-can-you-install-new-fonts-to-libreoffice-snap)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that LibreOffice was installed as a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) package.

Removing the snap package and installing by the traditional apt method by running the following commands solved the problem:

```
$ sudo snap remove libreoffice
$ sudo apt install libreoffice
```