# Google Chrome: Math symbols don't appear correctly

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I've been trying to figure out how to make the math symbols on [this page](http://lsusmath.rickmabry.org/psisson/putnam/putnam-web.htm) to work, but with no luck.

This is what I see:

[image]

I have tried changing the font in Chrome options but was unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see approximately the same with Firefox. Can you be more precise about which characters aren't rendered properly?

Comment: The å character should be a capital Sigma, the £ should be a "less than or equal" (or just "less than", maybe)... I haven't tried it on Firefox, maybe it's a problem with the webpage then. 
If it helps, I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally preinstalled Ubuntu does not contain some proprietary fonts.
The page uses *Symbol* font.

I installed it with the following actions:

1. Installed GNOME Font Viewer with `sudo apt-get install gnome-font-viewer` (or if you use MATE DE you can install MATE Font Viewer `sudo apt-get install mate-control-center`)
2. Downloaded *Symbol* font from [the link](https://github.com/IamDH4/ttf-wps-fonts/raw/master/symbol.ttf) with browser.
3. Opened downloaded font by clicking on it and clicked *Install font* button
4. Closed web browser and opened it again on page.
5. Got all equations rendered correctly.

Note: you can use [other question "How do I install fonts?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts) for screenshots.

Comment: Excellent, this solved it. Thank you so much!!